# All nodes in mapped linked at once?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a basic DFA (deterministic finite automata) generator. If you don't know what it is, it's more or less a basic state machine. Nodes are generated and systematically linked to another node with some data specified in JSON.

To do this, I have a dictionary of nodes. Each node is guaranteed have a unique ID, so I use the ID as the key, and the node as the value.

I populate my dictionary, and from there, go about linking each node to following nodes (states) it can transfer to. The transition state has an ID to the node it starts at, and an ID to the node it ends at. Each node has a map of references to nodes with the transition as the hash value (which is also guaranteed to be unique by the nature of being a DFA).

Here's where the issue is, when linking one node in my map with a following node, every other node simultaneously gets the link too!

So if I have nodes

```
[q0]  [q1]  [q2]
```

And I link q0 with q1 with a transition of 1, this happens:

```
[q0] -> [q1] <- [q2]
          ↺
```

I know I do not have collision errors though. If I perform any other action on a node here, the action is not acted on my every other node.

I create the dictionary of nodes like so:

```
dict_nodes = {}
alphabet = json_values["alphabet"]
for state in json_values["possible_states"]:
    dict_nodes[state["state_key"]] = node()
```

Then link them like this:

```
for transition in json_values["transitions"]:
    lexicon = transition["transition"]
    if lexicon not in alphabet:
        raise ValueError("Nodes with transitions outside of alphabet are not accepted")

dict_nodes[transition["start_key"]].add_following_state(dict_nodes[transition["end_key"]], lexicon)
```

The node class looks like this:

```
class node(object):
""" Following node paths that can be walked and their states """
following_states = {}
""" Determine if node is an accept state or not """
is_accept_state = False

def __init__(self):
    pass

def add_following_state(self, new_node, state):
    self.following_states[state] = new_node

""" Extra methods omitted """
```

Any idea why everything is getting linked at once?

Comment: Since you create ``following_states`` directly in the class (rather than in ``__init__()``), it's a class variable, shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: I... thank you. That did it.

Comment: If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.